# Pandas throws error after modifying dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a strange error when using pandas.

I have a function that bins and sorts data. This works completely fine. 
But the moment I try to subset the dataframe it does not work anymore while the dataframe looks the same.

code that throws error:

```
idxsort = dataframe[header].value_counts().sort_index()
bins = np.round(len(idxsort) / 10)
if bins < 10:
     bins = 10
gsort = idxsort.groupby(pd.cut(idxsort.index, bins=bins))
distribution = gsort.describe()['count']
```

This works with a full dataframe perfectly but when I modify it like this:

```
samples =  [4033, 4085, 4080, 4060, 4026, 4082, 4096, 4100, 4103, 4105, 4121]
dataframe = dataframe.set_index(dataframe.columns[0])
dataframe = dataframe.loc[samples, :]
dataframe = dataframe.reset_index()
```

and run it through the same code it does not work anymore.

What is going wrong here?

Edit: the error is "ValueError: Cannot cut empty array"

Answer (score 0):

Solved! By subsetting my dataset I did acidently generate some columns with only Na values.

I fixed it by adding: `dataframe.dropna(how='all', axis=1)`